# Save list with cookie and delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies, append

I have a script which allows to save and delete cookies: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V63Px/)

Type something in the input field and save. Do this twice or more, now delete the items and refresh. You will see the last deleted item is still  there. How is this possible??

ps. You can click the list to delete item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save list `values2` before removing clicked item. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V63Px/9/

Comment: @Youss Please, provide more details. it's your JsFiddle, just put `$(this).remove();` before `each`, as I understand you trying to delete clicked item?

Comment: Sorry, It seems your fiddle works, thank you very much:) I have put your code on my website [http://moskah.nl/] plaese take a look, you will notice I cant click the list items and delete them....Do you have any idea why that is ?